# boot from usb stick without the grub prompt

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, grub, live-usb

For some reason today when I went to boot from the usb stick the grub prompt opened up. The process is the following: I turn on the pc, open the boot menu, select to boot from the usb stick and then the grub menu always opens up at this point. I tried with a usb flashed with pop os 21.10, then 22.04 and then with linux mint, the grub prompt always opened up. The normal boot with my internal hard drive seems to be ok, this only happens when I select to boot from the usb stick.

I managed to still boot from the usb stick thanks to this guide https://linuxhint.com/boot-usb-using-grub/

**Question**: is there a way to directly boot from the usb stick when I select it from the boot menu instead of passing through the grub prompt which is bothersome? In the past it has always booted directly from it, without the grub prompt, I don't know what has changed now.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-at-the-beginning-of-boot This should help.

Comment: I had this same problem. When I installed on PC SSD, Mint 21 starts and works fine without Grub menu because I disabled it.